# Is there a shortcut or special-case when transforming long numbers from base-256 to base-255 and back?

Tags: c, optimization, rust, radix

I have many large numbers which are several hundred bytes long.

How can I efficiently transform these from base-256 into base-255, such that the numbers become up to one byte longer but don't use the value (or digit) 0xFF in any output byte?

(I have coded a general solution, but it's complexity O(n*n), as each input digit can affect many of the output digits.)

Is there a shortcut or special-case when transforming long numbers from base-256 to base-255 and back?

Comment: I doubt it. "Shortcuts" exist for converting between base-<power-of-same-number> numbers, while base-255 and base-256 are not under this category.

Comment: `O(n*n)` seems to be too much though...

Comment: @EugeneSh. Doesn't the hundredth digit in base-256 affect the first 99 digits of the output?  I'm probably in need of a non-trivial algorithm.

Comment: The trivial divide by new_base, take the rest, repeat until done is  is `O(log n)` in time.

Comment: @cafce25 Well, that assumes that you have some O(1) algorithm for the base-whatever division, which is unlikely with these specific bases.

Comment: base-255 -> base-256 can be probably done easier, as base-256 is easily obtained from the "native" binary representation of the result of `x[n-1]*255^(n-1)+x[n-2]*255^(n-2)..+x[0]`

Comment: I wonder if division could be speeded up by using multiplication by reciprocal? You would need to calculate a suitably long multiplier for the reciprocal though.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. O(n^2) is correct for the straightfoward approach of taking remainder and dividing in loop. The first division will take time indirectly proportional to the length meaning O(n). The length gets progressively smaller each pass, but that's not relevant because O(n + n-1 + n-2 + ... + 2 + 1 ) is still O( n^2 )

Comment: @fadedbee, Perhaps _post_ your "I have coded a general solution" and ask for O() improvements.  Also is the "several hundred bytes long" unbounded?  Are we dealing with _unsigned_ numbers?

Comment: Any reason for picking base-255 other than compactness? Converting from base-256 to base-128 (or some smaller power of 2) would be O(ndigits) but would have about 14.3% more digits.

Comment: I'm confused. To me, a base 256 number is just a "bignum" (e.g. gmplib's `mpz_t`) and conversion to 255 would be similar to having an `unsigned char` array similar to BCD (where each byte is a digit 0-9)!? If so, isn't this O(n)??? So that we're [all] on the same page, please edit your question and post exact descriptions of the format for [your] base256 and base255 numbers. And, post your [slow] working code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To speed this up you want to think about even larger bases.

The first step would be to convert the original "base 256" into either "base 1<<32" or "base 1<<64" (depending on what your CPU is). This reduces the number of digits in the number by a factor of 4 (or 8). If byte order ("endianess") is compatible and "length in bytes" is a multiple of 8 (which should be easy to ensure in earlier code) this may involve not actually doing anything (some hassle with type conversion and the strict aliasing rule in the source code that becomes zero bytes of machine code).

In a related way; instead of converting directly to "base 255" you could convert to "base 255*255*255*255" first; and then split each "large digit" into a pair of smaller "base 255*255" digits, then split those into smaller "base 255" digits. This splitting can be very fast with SIMD (split multiple digits at the same time).

These changes should make it almost 16 times faster. Essentially, if your division algorithm is "O(n*n)" it will become "O(n/4 * n/4)" or "O(n*n/16)". Of course "O(n*n/16)" is considered the same as "O(n*n)" despite being a lot faster.